# I can't publish my work in a Unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I try to publish my changes to the other members, these four items appear: [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaguO.png) [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kO2n.png)

I have not done any changes to those items, nor have I, to my knowledge, added them.

When I try to publish them, I get this error: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNEec.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved after I:

1. Closed the Unity project.
2. Let another member publish their work.
3. Reopened the Unity project.